# isset variables created using extract function

Tags: php

```
$array = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$count = count($array);

extract($array, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'var');
```

can the variables (created using extract function) be isseted automatically? to avoid "Notice: Undefined variable:" errors when error_reporting(E_ALL); is enabled.

thank you

I tried doing something of this sort, still needed to isset() whenever, the variables are used next in the code (when error_reporting(E_ALL); is enabled).

```
if(isset($var_0))
{    
$var_0 = filter_var($var_0, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);  
}
if(isset($var_1))
{
$var_1 = filter_var($var_1, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}
if(isset($var_2))
{
$var_2 = filter_var($var_2, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}
if(isset($var_3))
{
$var_3 = filter_var($var_3, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}
```

==========================

Alternatively, tried the one line if condition,

```
$var_0 = isset($var_0) ? filter_var($var_0, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : '';     
$var_1 = isset($var_1) ? filter_var($var_1, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : '';
$var_2 = isset($var_2) ? filter_var($var_2, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : '';
$var_3 = isset($var_3) ? filter_var($var_3, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : '';
```

while the error got subsided, but, a new problem arises i.e., variables (which are not created by extract function are getting isseted because of this one line if condition approach).

I am posting two of the routing rules (of two urls) in the website.

```
$pagename = "not-found.php";

//Different Routing Engine Rules follows

if ((isset($var_1)) && (($var_1 == "") || ($var_1 == "index.php"))) {


     if((isset($var_2)) || (isset($var_3)) || (isset($var_4)) || (isset($var_5)) || (isset($var_6)) || (isset($var_7)))
    {
      $pagename = "not-found.php";

    }
    else
    {

      $pagename = "default-home.php";

    }
}

if (($var_1 == "login")) 
{
//echo "Login Page URL\n";      

    if((isset($var_2)) || (isset($var_3)) || (isset($var_4)) || (isset($var_5)) || (isset($var_6)) || (isset($var_7)))
    {
      $pagename = "not-found.php";
    }
    else
    {
      $pagename = "login.php";  
    }
}

include "code/" . $pagename;
```

any help will be appreciated, thank you

Comment: When do you get a Notice: Undefined variable? Please clarify your question.

Comment: when error_reporting(E_ALL); is enabled.

Comment: Why don't you leave the variables in the array and **loop** through it?

Comment: `isset` is the least of your problems. Your routing logic is simply terrifically complicated and hard to scale. I'm not sure where to start to address your problems. Maybe I can interest you in [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/) as an intro into what `isset` is for and how it should/shouldn't be used.

Comment: @deceze thank you for the link about isset. The article explained things well. I use "!" symbol for variables  when checking them. Overall, thank you for the pointer about isset and it's usage, I will try to improve my routing logic better, thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then, no. It's still your responsibility to know what variables are available and act accordingly. You can simply disable these notices via `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE)` for the portion of code in question.

**Edit**

Looking at your updated question, I think it would be helpful if you could explain what you're trying to achieve. Personally, I see the use of `extract` as a bit of a code smell and there may be a better way :)

Comment: I am already doing it (i.e. disabling error_reporting(E_ALL);. I asked help only to know, if I can avoid isset() everytime I use the variable, especially when I have error_reporting(E_ALL); setting enabled, thank you

Comment: +1 for general advise, -1 for even mentioning disabling error reporting as a viable solution. Sorry, ±0. :)

Comment: the purpose is, I am using the created variables as part of url routes in the application.
what I am trying to do is explode the $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; into variables automatically using extract function. These variables are used to route requests (application based seo url setup). I am disabling error_reporting(E_ALL); when errors other than the isset() related were fixed. ia m posting here, as i wish to see if I can do this better.

Comment: @RaghuVeer, why is it necessary to use extract? Can you not just pass an associative array to the function being called? I think we'd really need a more complete example of what you're trying to do to give better advice.

Comment: updated the question with further details, i.e. added two routing rules (which work for two urls in the website)

Comment: If you're limited to this small set of variables, why not just use an associative array and forget about extract? `extract` pollutes the global namespace and is just asking for trouble when a variable pops up in the array you don't expect.

Comment: @MichaelMior is it a documented fact that extract pollutes the global namespace, instead of populating the scope that it is used in? I have never seen that anywhere. Extract can be useful when you have a large number of decisions to make based on the contents of an associated array, such as a secure form submission with many search criteria based on the user's combination of selections. Without `extract()`, an unreasonable amount of array lookups may need to be performed. Better to use extract (assuming it works in the local scope only) then to access an array 50 times.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge Extracting data into variables based on user input is just a bad idea. I would question the logic of the code in question if the alternative was accessing an array 50 times.

Comment: @MichaelMior Extracting directly from one of PHP's first level input sources is a bad idea. I agree. However, in a world where one has a system of pre-validation, sanitization, validation, and input translation, the resulting array is more than safe to extract, saving countless look ups of an array.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge We can agree to disagree :)

Comment: @MichaelMior Except, that I agree with you. My way of extracting is not purely based in user input.

Comment: I understand but I still think extract is almost never ever a good idea.